# Read out from another method

Tags: java

So I got this piece of code:

```
public static ArrayList<Vehicle> readVehicles() throws IOException {

    ArrayList<Vehicle> out = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try {
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("Vehicles.json"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray jsonvehicles = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Vehicles");
    Iterator i = jsonvehicles.iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject v = (JSONObject) i.next();
        /*
         * Engines(); Chassis(); Tires();
         */
        // out.add(new Vehicle(...);
    }
    return out;
}

public static ArrayList<Engine> readEngines() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Engine> out = new ArrayList<Engine>();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try {
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("Engines.json"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray jsonengines = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Engines");
    Iterator i = jsonengines.iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject v = (JSONObject) i.next();
        String name = (String) v.get("name");
        int price = (int) v.get("price");
        int quality = (int) v.get("quality");
        int maxSpeed = (int) v.get("maxSpeed");
        int maxAccelaration = (int) v.get("maxAcceleration");

        out.add(new Engine(name, price, quality, maxSpeed, maxAccelaration));
    }
    return out;
}
```

and so on, regarding at `tires()`, and chassis.

My question is, how do I get the output of for example, engine, into vehicle?

See, a vehicle consists of engines, chassis and tires. And a engine as the properties quality, name, price and so on. How do I kinda add this to a new vehicle?

It's probably already been asked, but I really don't know how to ask this (native language isn't English). Sorry if I sound really vague, but to be honest, I'm not sure what I'm asking.

Comment: you can call e.g. `readEngines()` in your `readVehicle()`method

Comment: you basicly just have to have different variables in the `Car` class. For example: `Engine engine; Tire[] tires;`. In the constructor you assign/ initialize these. In the end you just use `setXXX` and `getXXX` to reassign/ get the values for the corresponding fields.

Comment: I tried to call, readEngines() for example, but if I try to 

out.add(new Vehicle(.....)
what do I put between the braces? I tried this:

out.add(new Vehicle(readEngines(), readVehicle())

causing the error: 

The constructor Vehicle(ArrayList<Engine>, ArrayList<Chassis>, ArrayList<Tires>) is undefined

Comment: @EarthTudelft i think it´s more of a logical problem for you currently. When you do what you said you do you´d logically add every possible `Tire`, `Engine` and `Chassis` to each individual `Car` (the instance), as that´s what adding the whole `List` would make it look like. 
If you want it to work a bit more logical you have to get a specific `Tire` or more tires, a specific `Chassis` and a specific `Engine` out of this `List` and pass it to the constructor. how you identify which `Engine` etc does fit the current `Car` is up to your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kevin Esche said, you can do it by something like this (For example) :

> Car.java class file

```
private class Car{
    private Engine engine;
    private ArrayList<Tire> tires; 

    public void setEngine(Engine carEngine){
        this.engine = carEngine;
    }
    public Engine getEngine(){
        return this.engine;
    }
    public void addTire(Tire carTire){
        this.tires.add(carTire);
    }
}
```

> Engin java class file

```
private class Engine{
    private int horsepower;

    public int getHorsepower() {
        return horsepower;
    }

    public void setHorsepower(int horsepower) {
        this.horsepower = horsepower;
    }

}
```

> Tire.java file

```
private class Tire{
    private int size;

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

In addition, something is missing in your "readVehicle()" method code.
You need to write how to build a Vehicule from your Json Object.

So if your json file looks like :

```
{
     "carType": "Mercedes Classe B"
}
```

you will need to write in your code (readVehicle() method for example):

```
Vehicule vehicule = new Vehicle();
vehicule.setType(object.getString("carType"));
```